# Hide New Environment Numbering

Tags: environments

The object of my question is learning how to remove the numbering that lies adjacent to a new environment after its been called while being able to reference the counter number later using `\ref`. I've been looking for answers but it seems that everyone wants this numbering while I don't. I understand that I can use `\addtocounter{Problem}`, but I'd like something automated so that I don't have to worry about that every section or chapter. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{nameref}
\newcounter{Problem}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\theProblem}{\thechapter.\arabic{homework}}
  \newenvironment{Problem}[1][]{
    \refstepcounter{Problem}
    \paragraph{PROBLEM \theProblem~ #1}%
    }
    {
(end of problem)
    }%
\begin{document}

\chapter{New Chapter}

\begin{Problem}[A]

\label{Issue}
I want the problem number on the left to be hidden when using \nameref.
\end{homework}

I'm trying to hide the number when using \nameref{Issue}
\end{document}
```

I'm sorry, I forgot to include that I am trying to hide the problem number when using \nameref.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you remove the number, how can a reader know what you're referring to with `\ref`?

Comment: It seems as simple as removing `\theProblem` from your `Problem` environment definition... But there is little value in referencing something that doesn't have a corresponding number. Unless, of course, you might be interested in referencing the problem by some literal description.

Comment: Please complete your code to form a complete, small document we can compile. That's much more useful than a mere code fragment. In this case, it might also help us to understand what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want that `\nameref{Issue}` just prints “PROBLEM A”, you have to redefine `\@currentlabelname` before `\label` is seen:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{nameref}
\newcounter{Problem}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\theProblem}{\thechapter.\arabic{Problem}}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{Problem}[1][]
  {\refstepcounter{Problem}%
   \paragraph{PROBLEM \theProblem~#1}%
   \def\@currentlabelname{PROBLEM~#1}}
  {(end of problem)}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{New Chapter}

\begin{Problem}[A]
\label{Issue}
I want the problem number on the left to be hidden when using \texttt{\string\nameref}.
\end{Problem}

I'm trying to hide the number when using \nameref{Issue}
\end{document}
```

[image]